# Iterate over array Capybara Cucumber

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

I'm accessing a table on a webpage. After applying a specific filter, one data item in each row must contain a certain value.

I've tried to create an array out of the table data, making each row it's own index.

Once I have the index, I want to scope within this row to find the certain value I'm after.

So far, I've got the following:

```
results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tr')

    results_table.each do |row|


     within(results_table[row]) do
        table_data = all('table#clickable-rows td')
          expect(table_data[3]).to have_text TEXT
      end
    end
  end
```

It's the iteration I'm struggling with.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things wrong here - once you start iterating on the results_table row is the actual row element (not an index to the row), so you should not be indexing into results_table again.  Also, once you've called `within(element)` all CSS finds will then be relative to that element so you don't need to find the table again (unless looking for a table embedded in the original table).  You probably want something more like

```
results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')
results_table.each do |row|
  within(row) do
    table_data = all('td') # you could also just find the third one with nth-child if you only want that one column
    expect(table_data[3]).to have_text TEXT
  end
end
```

end

or without using within

```
results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')
results_table.each do |row|
  table_data = row.all('td')
  expect(table_data[3]).to have_text TEXT
end
```

One important thing to note here is that by default `all` doesn't wait for rows to appear, so if this is being run with a JS capable driver you probably want to use something like

```
results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr', minimum: 1) #you can adjust minimum if you need to wait for more rows to be on the page
```

to make sure the table rows have actually appeared on the page

Comment: Hi @Tom Walpole, I tried both solutions and had the same result for both.  RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text "TEXT" in ""

Comment: @Tom then the text isn't there - post the actual HTML you're trying to search

Comment: When using puts row.text, it's showing the whole row text and the specific text I'm after is included.  It's just when we try to scope to it, it fails.  This is the output of puts row.text 'A123ABC Ferrari 48 SORN Renew 28 Nov 2005.  I need every row to contain 'SORN' as it's filter criteria

Comment: @Tom where are the TD breaks in that text?

Comment: I have got it working.  The solution I'll put in the answer. It was to do with how I was locating the table rows.

Answer (score 0):

I was steered to a solution with help from the community on here.

My `results_table` and `table_data` variables needed to include tbody. Once I added this, it was able to find the desired content.

```
results_table = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr')
    results_table.each do |row|
      within(row) do
        table_data = all('table#clickable-rows tbody tr td') 
          expect(table_data[3]).to have_text TEXT
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: You still have a ton of extra unnecessary stuff in there -- the only reason including tbody would make a difference is if your row query was matching a row in the thead that didn't have the expected content.  In which case it means adding tbody to the first line correctly filtered the rows and the internal loop just becomes  `expect(row.all('td')[3]).to have_text TEXT`

Comment: That is much better!!! If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you